# minimize wp_query call to database

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, query-posts

I have a very basic question which can be done easily with raw sql query where instead of * we can name the columns of database we want output like

```
      select id,name,date from tableA where id>'100'
```

but same thing in `Wp_Query` is giving whole lot of junk data which is completely irrelevant to us. We can filter those data with `php` but the problem is it will definitely kill database as it is making lot of calls behind the scene.

We checked with `var_dump` and it was huge data 99% of not useful to us. We want to list only id and name column not columns like `PING_STATUS,COMMENT_STATUS,MENU_ORDER,COMMENT_STATUS` etc

```
 while ( $has_more_images ) {

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '100',
        'offset'         => $offset,
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_status'    => 'any',
        'orderby'        =>'ID',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'no_found_rows'  => true


    );


    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    var_dump( $the_query );

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WP_Query` is not a general-purpose method for querying the database. It's specifically designed for querying *posts* with the intention to loop over them and output templates for them.

If you just want arbitrary data from the `wp_posts` table, then you can just write SQL and use the [`$wpdb`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) object to run it:

```
$query       = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' ORDER BY ID LIMIT 100 OFFSET %d", $offset );
$attachments = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

if ( ! empty( $attachments ) ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $id   = $attachment->ID;
        $name = $attachment->post_title;
    }
}
```

This uses the `$wpdb->prepare()` method to safely add the `$offset` variable to the SQL query, and then uses `$wpdb->get_results()` method to run that query and return an array of objects for each result. The `$wpdb->posts` part of the query allows you to target the `wp_posts` table regardless of what the database prefix might be (Users can configure it to be something other than `wp_`, and on multisite each site has a different posts table).

Keep in mind that the *purpose* of the `wp_posts` table, and the attachment post type, is for that data to behave like posts, where things like the status and date are important. If you're trying to use posts for something that isn't like a 'post' then you probably shouldn't be using the posts table.

You seem to want to list the name of *everything* in the Media Library, and I'm honestly not sure why you'd want to do that, it's quite an odd thing to want to do. So if this isn't your actual use-case I'd recommend updating your question with whatever it actually is.

Comment: {$wpdb->prefix}posts or $wpdb->posts ??

Comment: No, `$wpdb->posts`. `$wpdb` has a reference to all the default tables with the prefix included. You'll only need to use `$wpdb->prefix` explicitly if you're referencing a custom table.

Comment: 2700 lines of var_dump changed to 100 lines as per 100 limit and same output. very happy

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple question, but it touches upon a complex matter of optimization that affects all computing, from chipsets and low level compilers to higher level systems like WordPress. Any hardware or software that serves a general purpose, must compromise in the way it handles requests. That means that every single request could probably be handled more efficiently if the system was purposely build for it.

So, in your case, you conclude that [`wp_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) translates to `SQL` in an inefficient way for your particular purpose. That is only to be expected, given the above. If you know which `SQL` query you want to run, the most efficient way to go is to simply pass that query through `wp_query`, and bypass any parsing by WP itself. Like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL ... the rest of your query";
$query = new WP_Query();
$query->parse_query($sql);
$posts = $query->get_posts();
```

A lesser known feature of WP is that you can [use filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters) to change the SQL query that `wp_query` would normally generate. You can use these filters to change the default compromises WP makes while parsing queries. You would use these if you will be running a specific type of queries which you want to optimize. But, once more, if you know exactly which SQL you want to run, just bypass WP's parsing.

Comment: They don't want post objects at all, and as far as I can tell they don't intend to use the loop either, so I don't know why putting SQL in WP_Query would be the right approach here. Wouldn't just running the SQL with `$wpdb` be preferable?

Comment: @JacobPeattie i was about to ask same question here.when i am using directly sql query why to go through any of wp functions like wp_query, have_post etc directly i will list 100 attachment and process. i thought there may be some way to reduce that if it is not there we are gong ahead with sql. atleast i will save precious mysql

Comment: @JacobPeattie Possibly, but the question specificly asks about `wp_query`